# Percentage (%) sign in GNU inline assembly (asm in C)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

What these lines of code are supposed to do?

```
mov ebx, %1

mov ecx, %0
```

I know that % means pointer but I need some more explanation. Why %1 and 0 - these specific numbers?

Comment: Is this inline assembly in c code?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Code like this is usually a sign of inefficiently-written inline asm.  Since it's `ebx` not `%%ebx`, this is `-masm=intel` syntax, moving operands *to* those registers.  Instead of that, just tell the compiler you want your inputs in those registers in the first place with `"c"(var0), "b"(var1)`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AT&T syntax, registers are refered to using a percent sign and then the registers name, i.e. `%eax`. The ones you showed with digits however have no meaning in assembly, they are used in inline assembly to refer to the input and output operands.

```
int i = 5;
int j;
asm ("mov %1, %0" : "=r"(j) : "r"(i)); //AT&T. Swap operands for Intel syntax
```

This would declare `i` and `j` as output and input arguments respectively. The `q` means, any general purpose register is fine. Unless you really need a specific register, you should always let your compiler choose whatever is convenient. Since you don't know beforehand which registers you get, they get assigned a number starting from 0. `%0` is the first argument, in this case the output argument `j` and `%1` is the input argument, `i`.

Comment: Your operands are reversed for AT&T syntax. It should be `asm ("mov %1, %0" : "=q"(j) : "q"(i))` . Yours likely appears to work because the compiler probably used the same register for the input and output constraints. I'd also recommend `r` instead of `q`. That would allow all general purpose registers whether in 64-bit or 32-bit code (in 32-bit code `q` constraint would only allow EAX,EBX,ECX, and EDX). You can also do this move using ASM without anything in the inline assembly with `asm ("" : "=r"(j) : "0"(i));` .

Comment: @MichaelPetch `Your operands are reversed for AT&T [...] I'd also recommend r instead of q` You're right, fixed. Seems like I expected `0` to be the input... One of them could probably also be a memory operand.  `You can also do this move using ASM without anything in the inline assembly` This would defeat the point of the example though.

Comment: I was just pointing out that an empty asm statement works too, I do understand that using `mov` was to be used as an example.

Answer (score 1):

%0 and %1 are the first two operands to the inline assembly block.
It's not regular x86, but special to gcc, I think.

See here: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html